# How investigate sporadic restarts

Tags: debian, embedded, reboot

The system is :
Debian 8.1 run on embedded system with ARM7V CPU 2 GB RAM and 4 GB flash.

The system sporadically restart itself couple time in day, before a week with appear very rare.

What is the best way find a reason of such behavior ?

Comment: have logs, preferably not just on storage, but on serial console or via network (because storage can be lost at this restart if it's really some driver/hardware etc. failure)

Comment: How many Amperes on the power supply? Any realtek wifi?

Comment: If the device is under high load (with crap drivers typical of arm) sometimes the Watchdog will reboot the device

Comment: I use POE as power supply, does it sensible to changes on AC netork changes.

Comment: About high load how can I catch that hw watchdog ran

Answer (score 0):

I first would run the last command and see when the restarts were happening, and once I pinpointed a time look in the system logs generally /var/log/messages, that would run out application or OS related issues. 
POE should be okay, but is the switch powering off the interface? I would also look at the switches logs.